# ToString в C++

Tags: c++

Как в этом языке конвертировать число в строку?

```
label->Text = trackBar->Value;
```

Comment: А я думал, что язык преисподней -- это "язык Ада"...

Comment: Ада - это язык Байрона.

Comment: @mikillskeg хотелось бы расшифровку.

Comment: @alexlz, язык Ада назван так в честь Ады Лавлейс, первого программиста в истории человечества и дочери лорда Байрона.

Comment: А. Когда-то читал, но уже забыл. В отличие от байки, как бабуля в общественном транспорте увидела у девушки в руках книгу "Программирование на языке АДА".

Comment: А я слышал вариант, где книга называлась просто "Язык Ада"

Comment: Возможно. Первый международно-стандартизованный язык объектно-ориентированного программирования, блин.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, такой книги, вообще-то, нет.  Ну это ж просто смешная байка.

Comment: В продаже нет, но.. Язык Ада: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/24038108/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

К сожалению, в С++2003 нет нормального стандартного способа конвертации чисел в строки. Возможные варианты решения:

1. `sprintf` - решение в стиле Си
2. `itoa` - ещё один вариант в стиле Си. Не является стандартной функцией, но многие реализации поддерживают.
3. `stringstream`:

   ```
   stringstream ss;    
   int i = 777;    
   ss << i;    
   string str = ss.str();
   ```
4. [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)
5. Для более сложных преобразований можно использовать [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/format/)

В С++11 появились наконец нормальные функции конвертации, в том числе [`std::to_string`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), перегруженная для разных числовых типов. В g++-4.7 работает нормально.

Answer (score 2):

atoi(); из stdlib.h

Гугл по прежнему помогает в решении подобных вопросов.

Comment: Это наоборот делает из строки число

Comment: аналогично str(); гугл все еще помогает в решении данного вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

[[@Fangog](/users/8519/fangog)](/users/8519/fangog), сам с удивлением обнаружил, что кроме sprintf() ничего стандартного нет. Если нужно, вот функция для разных систем счисления. От двоичной до 16-ричной общепринятые цифры. Для остальных (до 64-ричной) набор символов из base64 (RFC1113).

Вы может быть удивитесь, но `printf` в винде (по крайней мере 32-bit XP) неправильно работает с несколькими аргументами, если среди них есть long long (64-bit целое).

Столкнувшись с этим фактом, я написал функцию преобразования (ну и немного обобщил ее).
Если сочтете полезной - берите.

```
/*
  llstr.c avp 2011, 2012

  Convert long-long fixed integer (64-bit) to string in the specified radix
  (any 2..64 (bin, octal, decimal, hex ...) )
  Returns string length.
 */

#ifdef TEST
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#endif

int
my_llstr (long long v, // source for 'printing'
      int radix, 
      int unsign,  // if 1 then unsigned source
      char *res)   // memory for result
{
  const char *dig = "0123456789abcdef";
  static const char cb64[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
  int          rem[65], sp = 0;   // stack for reminders
  char        *p = res;           // for return length
  unsigned long long   u = v;     // use if unsign == 1

  if (!res)
    return 0;
  if (radix < 2)
    radix = 2;
  if (radix > 64)
    radix = 64;
  if (radix > 16)
    dig = cb64;

  if (unsign) {
    while (u >= radix) {
      rem[sp++] = u%radix;
      u = u/radix;
    }
    *res++ = dig[u];
  } else {
    if (v < 0) {
      *res++ = '-';
      v = -v;
    }
    while (v >= radix) {
      rem[sp++] = v%radix;
      v = v/radix;
    }
    *res++ =  dig[v];
  }

  while (sp)
    *res++ =  dig[rem[--sp]];
  *res = 0;
  return res-p;
}

#ifdef TEST
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  long x;
  int  n;
  char buf[100];
  int r = av[1]? atoi(av[1]): 10;

  while (scanf("%ld",&x) == 1) {
    n = my_llstr(x, r, 0, buf);
    printf ("%s\n",buf);
  }

}
#endif
```

Вот, посмотрел свежим взглядом и чуть подправил (теперь указатель на цифры устанавливается один раз в начале).

Comment: Спасибо! После шарпа, плюсы для меня темный лес ><

Comment: @Fangog, если хотите нормально писать на С++, то сначала хорошенько освойте чистый Си (и posix). 

Потом сами для себя решите в каком стиле какие задачки писать.

Comment: Где-то попадались ltoa/itoa, но они в стандарт явно не вошли.

Comment: Ну да. С++ - язык не для слабонервных и не для слабовольных...

Comment: Ну можно обобщить и далее. Он вообще не для людей.

Comment: А для кого?

Comment: @mikillskegg А вот этого я не знаю. Это надо у специалистов по C++ спрашивать.

Comment: @mikillskegg (по исчерпанию лимита комментариев к вопросу -- здесь)

П.Венгер "Программирование на языке ADA", М.:"Мир", 1983г., 240 стр., 45 000 экз.

Comment: Понятно. Буду знать.

Comment: С++ - язык для специалистов по С++

Answer (score -1):

Начиная с С++11, в языке есть функция [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
int n = 1;
std::string str = std::to_string(n);
```